# guest subdirectory in /media?

Tags: ubuntu, media

I've observed a directory named 'guest-bizm7r' amongst the other users listed under the /media directory. I can access it only as root, and its empty. What is this? I don't recall mounting any usb media as a guest.
Is this a randomly generated name for a guest media directory? Why wouldn't it simply be named 'guest'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `mount` command you can see, what is mounted and where. If it gives too long output (unfortunately, since around a decade, linuxes started to trash their mount points with crap), then a

```
mount | grep /media
```

will filter the output to the `/media`.

If you aren't very trust in your system, then check the device in `cat /proc/mounts`. If there are troubles on the system, the `mount` output can sometimes lie (although it is very unlikely), but the `/proc/cpuinfo` can't (because it is not a generated file, but the actually existing kernel mount table).

You will see, what is mounted there.

If there is nothing (doublecheck `/proc/ḿounts`!), then nothing is mounted here. Check, is there some important in this directory, also the hidden files (`ls -la /media/guest-bizm7r`).

If there is nothing, then the most probable cause of this directory, that it was once mounted (for example, by putting into an usb disk), then a system freeze or not ordinary shutdown happened, and later this directory wasn't removed automatically. In this case, you can make up for with an `rmdir /media/guest-bizm7r` command.

Comment: Thanks. There's no record of it anywhere else. I deleted it.